# Google Calendar API with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension that will interact with the Google Calendar API in order to add events to my calendar. I am more or less following the directions [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) but the problem is that Chrome's Content Security Policies are blocking the script tags. To try to solve this, I downloaded https://apis.google.com/js/api.js and imported it with `<script src="api.js"></script>`. However, now I get the error:

> "Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.-F_i8pxym_s.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCOcSmYYH6pFUBh5t_7PICWuDXqniQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

It seems that the script I imported tries to download another script online. Should I download that one too? If not, how should I proceed? Also, given the nature of the Chrome Extension, will other parts of the example I linked above fail?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this "Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.", I think it's stating the solution here, you should set

```
script-src-elem
```

along with the

```
script-src
```

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Content-Security-Policy: style-src <source>;
Content-Security-Policy: style-src-elem <source>;

Comment: Checkout https://docs.w3cub.com/http/headers/content-security-policy/style-src-elem for more info

Comment: Just tried it and it says this feature was depreciated with version 3 of manifest, which I am using.

Comment: Check the documentation for manifest version 3